# MAMP Web pages not found

Tags: mamp

I have been running MAMP for about a year with no problems. Today when I try to load the pages I have hosted there I get a 404 error. I'm not sure what has changed. The file path to the document root is the same. Does any one have any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
Mac: 10.12.6
Mamp: 4.2
PHP: 7.1.6
Web server: Apache
MySQL: 5.6.35
Ports: 
   Apache: 8888
   Nginx:  7888
   MySQL:  8889
```

Would any other info be helpful?

Thank you!

Ben

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my problem, I'll share it here in case it helps someone else.

When I first configured MAMP I had set the port for Apache to the computers default port, 80. That way I could go to localhost/mywebsite. Somehow the port got changed to 8888 which is how MAMP comes out of the box. With that port setting, to find my pages I would have had to go to localhost:8888/mywebsite. I change the port back to the default port and the problem was fixed.